# Weyl theorem, compact and relatively compact operators

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, spectral-theory, compact-operators

Weyl's Theorem says that if $A$ is a $T$-compact operator on a Banach space $X$, then $T$ and $T+A$ have the same essential spectrum.

To be $T$-compact, $A$ must satisfy two conditions

(1) $D(T)\subset D(A)$

(2) For any bounded sequence $\{u_n\}\subset D(T)$ such that $\{Tu_n\}$ is bounded then $\{Au_n\}$ contains a convergent sub-sequence.

I have a few questions:

(1) From what I understand, the definition of being compact is that for any bounded sequence $\{u_n\}\subset X$ then $\{Au_n\}$ contains a convergent sub-sequence. Thus it implies that the domain of a compact operator be all of $X$. Is that right?

(2) If $A$ is compact, it is automatically $T$-compact, thus satisfies the condition of the theorem. Is that right?

(3) If I have an operator $T+A$ with both $T$ and $A$ having each a "natural" domain such that the condition $D(T)\subset D(A)$ be not satisfied. However, $D(T+A)=D(T\cap A)$. Then one could reduce the domain $T$ and $A$ to $D(T+A)$. Then the condition (1) of relative compactness would automatically be satisfied and only condition (2) is needed to be checked. Then, in the end, one just need to check Condition (2) on $D(T+A)$ to apply Weyl's theorem. Is that right?

(4) Finally, I am in the following situation: I can check that for any bounded sequence $\{u_n\}\subset D(A)$, then $\{Au_n\}$ has a converging subsequence. So, "$A$ is compact on its domain". Does such a notion exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1), one usually demands that a compact operator have domain all of $X$. Strictly speaking you don't *need* to do this, you could simply ask for "compact on its domain" as you write in (4), but this notion is rather pointless, as any densely defined operator that is "compact on its domain" admits a unique extension to a globally defined operator that is compact and continuous. For (2) any compact operator is $T$-compact for any $T$ as you remark.

For (3), what you write is correct, but note that if you change the domain of $T$ to $D(T)\cap D(A)$ then the resulting operator may not be densely defined. Further this operation of changing the domain can completely destroy the spectrum, so that the spectrum of your modified $T$ has nothing to do with the previous $T$. You will thus not gain insight into $T$ by modifiying its spectrum so that $A$ becomes $T$-compact.

For (4), as remarked above "compact on its domain" does not seem helpful, as any such operator admits a unique bounded extension with domain all of $X$ that is still compact. First note that if for every bounded sequence $u_n$ you have that $Au_n$ has a convergent sub-sequence, then $Au_n$ can never be unbounded for $u_n$ a bounded sequence. As such the operator $A$ is a bounded operator and you may uniquely extend its domain to be all of $X$ (assuming $A$ is densely defined). $A$ will still remain compact: If $u_n$ is an arbitrary bounded sequence define $\tilde u\in D(A)$ so that $\|\tilde u_n - u_n\|≤\frac1n$, then $A(\tilde u_n-u_n)\to0$ and if $A(\tilde u_n)$ admits a convergent subsequence then so does $A(u_n)$.

Comment: First, thank you very much. Everything makes sense. However, for (3), I would assume $D(T+A)$ is dense since $T+A$ would be the operator to study. It seems my goal (and the usefulness of that theorem) is to study the spectrum of $T+A$ by looking at the simpler $T$ on $D(T+A)$. So destroying or altering the spectrum of $T$ would not be my concern as long as its essential spectrum correspond to the one of $T+A$. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. Let $\tilde T$ be $T$ with the domain reduced to $D(T)\cap D(A)$ and suppose that this domain dense. This $\tilde T$ can have a different spectrum and a different essential spectrum than $T$. The operator $\tilde T +A$ will have the same essential spectrum as $\tilde T$ if $A$ is $\tilde T$-compact, but this can change the essential spectrum. I think in general you can only get $\sigma_{ess}(\tilde T)\subseteq \sigma_{ess}(T)$.

Comment: My goal is to study the spectrum of the operator $L=T+A$ with domain $D(L)=D(T+A)=D(T)\cap D(A)$.  $L=T+A=\tilde{T}+\tilde{A}$, where $\tilde{T}$ and $\tilde{A}$ are the operators $T$ and $A$ restricted to the domain $D(L)=D(T+A)$. This last equality between $T+A$ and $\tilde{T}+\tilde{A}$ is valid on $D(L)$. Written as $L=\tilde{T}+\tilde{A}$ though, I have that  $\tilde{A}$ is $\tilde{T}$-compact and thus really (now that I think of it, thanks to your comments), the essential spectrums of $\tilde{T}$ and $L$ are the same. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. $L$ and $\tilde T$ will have the same essential spectrum if $\tilde A$ is $\tilde T$-compact. This would give you $\sigma_{ess}(L)\subseteq \sigma_{ess}(T)$.

Comment: Thank you for all your time on this. I really appreciate it.